# How to create hidden Firefox Extension?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, xul

Is it possible to create Firewox extension that will not shown in Extensions List? And so cannot be deinstalled manually?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Sounds suspicious and I suggest you justify your intent.

Comment: It's one of the hurdles FireFox needs to overcome it it wants to become accepted in the enterprise - Admin-installed extensions should not be removable by non-admin users.

Comment: Why? It's not like it's hard for an organisation to control how their employees interact with the web anyway.

Comment: @MSalters: I'd say you just need to add the extension to the Firefox program directory, not to the user profile directory.

Comment: I don't think this is necessary for enterprise - I can't think of anything an extension needs to do that can't be better served using other tools. Page filtering can be done on the server, file access restrictions can be done using domain controls and so on.

Comment: @Tomalak: see Mozilla bug #474289. @Skizz: extensions are often used to make things possible. E.g. easy integration with non-web application on PC.

Comment: @MSalters: I see. Good point, didn't know that. (Link: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=474289)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this [mozillazine entry](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Uninstalling_extensions#Malicious_extensions) and this [forum entry](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=948945). These extensions are somehow installed via the registry and supposed to be malicious - so there's no use for this except if you want to be on some malware blacklist.

For private use or administration use like MSalters suggested in his comment, "hidden" (for some users) extensions could be useful, but this should be implemented by Mozilla first.

Answer (score 1):

To Hide an extensions/addons in the list of extension `about:addons` simply follow these few simple steps:

- (1) Create an a zipfile **myextenios.zip** (firefox extension are actually zip files) having this structure:

```
myextension.zip
|
|--chrome.manifest
|--install.rdf
|--[content]
    |--hideExtensions.css
```

- (2) The **chrome.manifest** should have this content:

```
content   myextension              content/
style chrome://mozapps/content/extensions/extensions.xul chrome://myextension/content/hideExtensions.css
style about:addons chrome://myextension/content/hideExtensions.css
```

- (3) The **install.rdf** should have this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<RDF xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"  xmlns:em="http://www.mozilla.org/2004/em-rdf#">

  <Description about="urn:mozilla:install-manifest">
    <em:id>myextension@yoursite.de</em:id>
    <em:name>myextension</em:name>
    <em:description>This addon hides addons entries in about:addons</em:description>
    <em:optionsURL></em:optionsURL>
    <em:iconURL></em:iconURL>
    <em:version>1.0</em:version>
    <em:creator>your name</em:creator>
    <em:homepageURL>http://www.yourside.de</em:homepageURL>
    <em:type>2</em:type>
    <em:targetApplication>
      <Description>
        <em:id>{ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}</em:id>
        <em:minVersion>4.0</em:minVersion>
        <em:maxVersion>14.*</em:maxVersion>
      </Description>
    </em:targetApplication>
  </Description>
</RDF>
```

- (4) Lastly the file **hideExtensions.css** has to have the following content:
  *(note: of course you might wanna adjust the name of the extension you want to hide)*

```
.addon[name="1. Name of addon to hide"],
.addon[name="2. Name of addon to hide"],
.addon[name="3. Name of addon to hide"],
.addon[name="myextension"]
{
display:none;
}
```

- (5) Rename the **myextension.zip** to **myextension.xpi** so that it recognized as a extension + install it by dragging the file into Firefox browser window.

### Conclusion:

Most of the steps baove are equal to those of the creation of any other firefox extension. Therefore anybody with the knowledge to create an firefox addon/extension can also cause this extension **not to show up** in the addon list you see when you enter **about:addons**. Consequently if you have just one malicious firefox extension (virus) then you cannot trust Firefox as much to even see this virus-extension in the list.

Comment: Hi, I check your solution at bootstrap extension and I get an error that **E/GeckoConsole( 2029): [JavaScript Warning: "Bootstrapped manifest not allowed to use 'style' directive."** Have you any idea how to hide bootstrap extentions from **about:addons** list?