# How to create hidden chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Basically this question for chrome,
"[How to create hidden Firefox Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780960/how-to-create-hidden-firefox-extension)".

Thanks

Comment: Why exactly would you link to a question that already has an answer adding a variation and think that someone would give an answer?

Comment: just asking is this the same procedure for chrome?

Comment: You may want to read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page before asking.  The problem is that all information relevant to the question should be in the question itself and this question is far too broad.

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the other question, so I have re-opened it. Why do you want to "hide" an extension? It is technically possible, but I am not going to say how because I cannot think of *any* legitimate purpose for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it sounds like you're trying to build malware. If that's not the case, I'd suggest you clarify your intent.

However, it sounds like the closest thing to what you're looking for is Chrome's "Enterprise Policy" system. It's meant for use by large organizations to centrally manage hundreds of Chrome installations remotely, but it's also popular among malware developers (for the same reason). Your extension won't be "hidden," since Chrome doesn't allow for hidden extensions, but the user won't be able to uninstall it through `chrome://extensions`.

I've never worked with it before, so I can't give much more detail, but [here's a link](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/188453?hl=en&ref_topic=2936229) to a Google page that explains it a bit.

Again, you should really reconsider whatever it is that you're doing. If you need your code to be invisible to its user, you're probably doing something you shouldn't be.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8K0dAnk.jpg ,like hide adblock plus (just curious).

Answer (score 0):

Make a chrome app instead of an extension. It will appear in the apps window but not in the extensions window. I don't know of any other way. Chrome is fairly locked down.